# With vue-material, how can I have text wrap instead of overflow to ellipsis in a list?

Tags: css, vue.js, material-design, vue-material

I have:

```
        <md-list-item>
          <md-icon v-bind:style="{color: transcript.color}">account_circle</md-icon>

          <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <p>{{ transcript.text }}</p>
          </div>

          <md-button class="md-icon-button md-list-action">
            <small>some stuff</small>
          </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
```

The problem is that `transcript.text` can be longer than a line, so there's a `text-overflow: ellipsis` set. I tried to add `text-overflow: visible !important` as a scoped style, but that seems to be ignored.

[image: vue-]

So how can I have my text break normally and extend to multiple lines?

Comment: there is no visible as value of text-overflow : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Values

Comment: So then what can I do to have it overflow normally and break on words?

Comment: look at white-space https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space or word-break https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.md-list-item-text p {
  white-space: normal;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

That did it!